# Dictionary: How do I minimize space in a hash table and space for unused char array elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, hash

I am writing a program that reads a text document of 200,000 dictionary words. I will compare it with another document of 2,000,000 words to count the lines that are not in the dictionary. I will only be storing alphabetical characters `a-z` (26 characters). Thus I only need 5 bits to represent each one. The maximum length of a character is `29` `(30 including the null character)`. I will also need to consider later on if the dictionary only contains words that at less than `7 characters`.

The conditions for this system are that it has its own custom allocator that I **must** use. So whenever I use the "new" (or any other sort of heap memory allocation) to dynamically allocate memory, it will use up **AT LEAST** `32 bytes` of memory each time the `new` keyword is used. To save memory, I would need to initialize larger sizes of `char arrays`.

I am also not allowed to read the dictionary words in the file directly. They will be provided to me in an array called `dictionaryWords` and will be destroyed after I am done constructing my hash table. So pointing to the words given to me is not plausible.

The program must run in less than `1 second`.

I.E.

```
Dictionary:
abc
lkas
ddjjsa
dada

Word Doc:
abc
lkas
weee
dada
jajaja

Wrong Numbers List: 3, 5
```

It will put numbers 3 and 5 into an array for the line numbers in Word Doc that are not in the dictionary.

I am keeping the `200,000` dictionary words in a Hash Table, so lookup from the word document to the hash table is `O(n)` for `n` number of words. The problem is that my hash table needs to rehash with a load factor of `0.5`, so it must rehash and double its size whenever it is half full. This leaves me with a wasted `200,000` empty hash entries that take up memory. Since the maximum word length is `30`, and a char takes `1 byte`, it will cost `30 bytes` per word in my hash entry. I am wasting `30 characters * 1 byte * 200,000 empty entries = 6000000 bytes / 6MB` of memory space in the heap while the program is running. I want to minimize the space usage as much as possible, but be able to run in O(n) time.

This is my hash entry for my hash table. You can see here, for a table size of 200,000 words, I will need 400,000 of these entries to keep a load factor of 0.5

```
struct HashElement
{
    char element[30];

    HashElement(char * word) 
      {
        memset(element, '\0', 30); //Set all bits to NULL for collision checking
        if (e != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(element, word);
        }
      }
};
```

If I represented each character with only 5 bits, I would be able to save 3/8's of my wasted space.

I have considered the pointer approach for my Hash Entries:

```
struct HashElement
{
    char * element;

    HashElement(char * word) 
      {
        element = NULL;
        if (e != NULL)
        {
            element = word;
        }
      }
};
```

But using the `new` keyword will use up `AT LEAST` `32 bytes` for this system. So each time I initialized the hash entry's element, it will cost `32 bytes` no matter what the word length size is. If I wanted to diverge this problem to only containing 7 characters per line in the word document, I would be in trouble because I only need `8 bytes` for each word, and I am using `32 bytes`.

Comment: I was thinking bits* my bad.

Comment: Something is very wrong with your understanding of hash tables. When you resize the hash table, you aren't creating more entries in it, just more buckets that can hold zero or more entries.

Comment: Since the smallest data structure is 8 bits, I would suggest, your only option is to recode the data into 5 bit chunks then reorganize it into 8 bit chunks. if the strings are short you won't find a huge space saving.

Comment: Could you please re-check your question? It seems to me that you are confusing “characters”, “words” and “lines”. The math for 46875 bytes equals 45MB seems also off, plus, it's most certainly heap-allocated memory and not stack space. Those errors are benign enough to still allow the post to get your basic point across but it would be easier to understand what you're asking if the question were a bit cleaner.

Comment: `6000000 bytes / 6GB`. Off by a thousand. Giga is a thousand million; the number you compute is six million, or six **M**B. Not worth worrying about these days. (And where does it say you need to keep your LF under 0.5?)

Comment: Note: in `C`, one could allocate the entire hashtable as one piece. (even in global and/or static memory, since the size is known in advance). The strings could be allocated as one consecutive *string space* (including the NULs) , too. So the fundamental *problem* here seems to be the tight coupling of C++'s constructors and the memory allocator.

Comment: You don't need to rehash, since you know the size(200K) in advance, so just allocate a fixed size table.This will cost you about 8MB of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You're working on a hard problem when there are lots of easy problems you need to solve first. Solving all the easy problems will likely be sufficient, so you don't need to work on the hard problem of compacting bits into fewer bytes.

1. Why allocate 30 bytes just because you might need up to that many?
2. Why allocate elements for empty hash buckets?

Comment: This seems to be good advice. After those low-hanging fruits are harvested, it seems unlikely that the – very moderate, by today's standards – remaining memory consumption of the program would cause any actual problem. I would of course even start by simply using `std::unordered_map<std::string>` and see how well it does. Maybe there is no need to optimize this at all.

Comment: @5gon12eder Exactly. And on the off chance that doesn't do it, just changing `std::string` to a compressed string class would get the last step fairly easily.

Comment: I edited the main post. Each dynamic allocation will take at the very least `32 bytes`. So it costs `32 bytes` minimum each time the `new` keyword is used. As for the empty hash buckets, wouldn't each hash bucket still cost memory if I used a pointer? Since a pointer costs `8 bytes` per bucket on a 64 bit system.

And as for std::string, it will still cost `32 bytes` per word of any length less than `32` because `std::string` uses the "new" keyword and resizes when needed in its implementation.

Comment: @TommySaechao It depends what allocator you use. You may need a custom allocator, but save the hard problems until you've solved the easy ones. Yes, each hash bucket costs memory, but if it's 8 bytes, then 400,000 buckets is 3MB. You're focused on the wrong problems.

Comment: You could also memory map the text document and use pointers into it. But I wouldn't bother because I think if you do the simple stuff, it will be more than enough. Your problem is quite simple and doesn't require an exotic solution.

Comment: Edited main post again* I **must** use the allocator given to me. Also pointing to the words in the file is not an option, since they will be destroyed after constructing my hash table.

Comment: @TommySaechao It sound like you have a large number of bizarre, arbitrary constraints. Trying to explain them all will make your question so specific that it will turn into "do my complex job for me".

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple string compressor class that will take a string of characters between 'a' and 'z' inclusive and compress each 8 bit representation to 5 bit and splitting the resulting binary, back into 7 bit representations.  Since each character is still represented by a unique number the hash of the word should still be as unique as expected:

```
class StringCompressor
{
public:
    static string Compress( string );
    static string ToBinary( long long input , int length );
    static int ToInt( string input );
    static string Decompress( string );
};

string StringCompressor::Compress( string input )
{
    stringstream ss;
    for ( char c : input )
    {
        string temp = ToBinary( ( c - 'a' ) , 5 );
        ss << temp;
    }
    ss << string( ( 7 - ( ss.str().length() % 7 ) ) , '0' );
    string temp = ss.str();
    ss.str( "" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i += 7 )
    {
        string temp2 = temp.substr( i , 7 );
        ss << (char)ToInt( temp2 );
    }
    return ss.str();
}
string StringCompressor::Decompress( string input )
{
    stringstream ss;
    for ( char c : input )
    {
        string temp = ToBinary( c , 7 );
        ss << temp;
    }
    string temp = ss.str().substr( 0 , ss.str().length() - ( ss.str().length() % 5 ) );
    ss.str( "" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i += 5 )
    {
        ss << (char)( ( ToInt( temp.substr( i , 5 ) ) ) + 'a' );
    }
    return ss.str();
}
string StringCompressor::ToBinary( long long input , int length )
{
    string output( length , '0' );
    for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        long long test = pow( 2.0 , i );
        if ( input >= test )
        {
            output[( length - 1 ) - i] = '1';
            input -= test;
        }

    }
    return output;
}
//Take a string representation of a binary number and return the base10 representation of it.  
//There's no validation of the string
int StringCompressor::ToInt( string input )
{
    int length = input.length();
    int output = 0;
    double temp = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        temp = ( input[( length - 1 ) - i] - '0' );
        output += pow( 2.0 , i ) * temp;
    }
    return output;
}
```